# How Do I get Notification Intent Data

Tags: java, android, notifications

I want to show a notification at some event, that's working fine, I am also landing on an activity I want but problem is that, intent data is empty, please here, Here is the code

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MovieDetailActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra(Constants.MOVIE_ID, cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.ID)));
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_download)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle(cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.NAME)))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText(cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.REALEASE_DATE)));
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build()
        );
```

I am sending some data using intent, in this line.

```
resultIntent.putExtra(Constants.MOVIE_ID, cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.ID)));
```

I am receiving data here but it Null.

```
Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
    mMovieId = receivedIntent.getIntExtra(Constants.MOVIE_ID, -1);
```

Please help, I have spent whole day on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass into intent String so you can't get Integer from intent, that's why you get null.

So change this line:

```
mMovieId = receivedIntent.getIntExtra(Constants.MOVIE_ID, -1);
```

to

```
 mMovieId = receivedIntent.getStringExtra(Constants.MOVIE_ID);  
// and simply parse string to integer  
       int id = Integer.parseInt(mMovieId);
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, I solved the issue but now facing another issue I land on MovieDetailActivity directly that's good but I can't go back to main activity since it's not on the stack and application terminates..

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not on the stack"? You have no button to go back, do you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

You need change your PendingIntent for:

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

I hope it solve your problem.